# Is it possible to write an outlook add-in that modifies the color of the user interface?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I'd like to write an outlook add-in that changes the color of the Outlook window when the user opens an e-mail that comes from a sender external to the company.

Can someone tell how to change the color of the outlook window? Also, will I need to use MAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you're concerned, it is not possible.

Since 2007, the color of the Outlook UI is defined by the user's color preference (Blue, Silver, or Black, or in 2013: White, Grey, Dark Grey). There is no API provided to allow add-ins to change this setting, let alone on a per-window basis.

Hypothetically it is possible to inject code into the Outlook process and hijack the window painting methods, but this would require a huge amount of reverse-engineering skill on your part.

Comment: "effort" instead of "skill" would be a bit more accurate.

Comment: I disagree - I've put a *lot* of effort into RCE/disassembling some basic database software and got nowhere - because I lacked the skills and understanding of what I'm doing. "Work smarter, not harder", etc.