# How do you modify another window's background color?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Suppose that you have a 3rd party application that's just a red window. Is there a straightforward way to change its color once you obtain the window handle?

Comment: It's forms. Nothing is straight forward. ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406306/is-it-possible-to-write-an-outlook-add-in-that-modifies-the-color-of-the-user-in ?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the other app is a WinForms app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with so far is to use `Graphics.FillRectangle`

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(handle);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10000, 10000));
```

Complete winform working example:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Window Name"))
                {
                     IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                    if ((int)handle != 0)
                    {
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(handle);
                        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, new Rectangle(0, 0, 10000, 10000));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You also can try obtain window size information by using [GetWindowRect](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowrect.html) as described here: [Get A Window's Bounds By Its Handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415222/get-a-windows-bounds-by-its-handle)
to avoid using 10000 for width and height.